# How to show two calculated columns to an existing table

Tags: sql

I would like to pull a report that will add two columns to the first two columns of an existing table (Shipment_Info). Shipment_Info has three columns ShipmentID and ItemID and Item_Status. ItemID values are always unique, but ShipmentIDs will repeat because different Items can be in the same shipment, and item status can be in different states (Allocated, Filled and Packed)

I want to run a query that will add two column to the existing table (first two columns).  The first new column (Shipment_Size) will show how many unique items there are in that specific shipmentID, and the 2nd new column (Shipment_ready) will show if the entire shipmentID is ready to be shipped.  For an shipmentID to be ready to be ItemIDs must be in a "Packed" status.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

DB Table: Shipment_INFO

| ShipmentID | ItemID | Item_status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 20001 | Packed |
| 10002 | 20002 | Allocated |
| 10002 | 20003 | Packed |
| 10003 | 20004 | Filled |
| 10004 | 20005 | Packed |
| 10004 | 20006 | Packed |
| 10004 | 20007 | Packed |
| 10005 | 20008 | Filled |
| 10005 | 20009 | Packed |
| 10006 | 20010 | Filled |

Ideal output.

| ShipmentID | ItemID | Shipment_Size | Shipment_Ready |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 20001 | 1 | Yes |
| 10002 | 20002 | 2 | No |
| 10002 | 20003 | 2 | No |
| 10003 | 20004 | 1 | No |
| 10004 | 20005 | 3 | Yes |
| 10004 | 20006 | 3 | Yes |
| 10004 | 20007 | 3 | Yes |
| 10005 | 20008 | 2 | No |
| 10005 | 20009 | 2 | No |
| 10006 | 20010 | 1 | No |

Someone help me with getting the Shipment_Size using this query, but I'm struggling to figure out how to integrate the the Shipment_Packed column to the query below.

```
select s.shipmentID, s.ItemID, i.Shipment_Size 
from Shipment_INFO s 
  inner join ( select shipmentID, count(*) as Shipment_Size 
  from Shipment_INFO 
  group by shipmentID ) i on i.shipmentID=s.shipmentID`
```

Comment: Always tag your SQL requests with the DBMS you are using. I've posted a standard SQL answer that works in many DBMS, but not in all. So tell us whether you are using MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, whatever, so as to only get answers that work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example for you :

```
  select ShipmentID,ItemID,
           count(ItemID) over (partition by ShipmentID) Shipment_Size,
          case when 
      sum(case when Item_status='Packed' then 1 else 0 end) OVER (partition by ShipmentID ) =count(ItemID) over (partition by ShipmentID)
                   then 'Yes' else 'no' end as Shipment_Ready
      from Shipment_INFO
    group by ShipmentID,Item_status,ItemID
```

[image]
demo :https://dbfiddle.uk/80HA0Njd

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
select
    shipmentid,
    itemid,
    count(*) over (partition by shipmentid) as shipment_size,
    case
        when (
            select count(*) from shipment_info si2
            where si2.shipmentid = si.shipmentid
            and si2.item_status = 'Packed'
        ) = count(*) over (partition by shipmentid)
        then 'Yes'
        else 'No'
    end as shipment_ready
from
    shipment_info si
```

or:

```
with
    shipment_status as (
        select
            shipmentid,
            count(1) as shipment_size,
            sum(case item_status when 'Packed' then 1 else 0 end) as packed_count
        from
            shipment_info
        group by
            shipmentid
    )
select
    si.shipmentid,
    si.itemid,
    ss.shipment_size,
    case ss.packed_count
        when ss.shipment_size then 'Yes'
        else 'No'
    as shipment_ready
from
    shipment_info si
    join
    shipment_status ss on ss.shipmentid = si.shipmentid
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to select all rows, but for each row look at its whole shipment. To do this use analytic funtions with `OVER (PARTITION BY shipmentid)`:

```
select
  shipmentid,
  itemid,
  count(*) over (partition by shipmentid) as shipment_size,
  min(item_status) over (partition by shipmentid) = 'Packed' as shipment_ready
from shipment_info
order by itemid;
```

I am using a trick here. 'Packed' is the last status in alphabetical order. So if the minimum status for a shipment is 'Packed', then all its items are packed and the shipment is ready.