# How do I join 2 tables and calculate 1 new column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm need to get 3 new columns with my SQL query.  The first 2 columns only requires 1 table (Shipment_Info), but the 3rd column requires the 2nd table (Item_Info).

1. 1st new column = Shipment_Size (# of itemsID in that shipment)
2. 2nd new column = Shipment_ready (entire shipmentID is ready to be shipped. For an shipmentID to be ready to be shipped all the ItemIDs must be in a "Packed" status)
3. 3rd new column = Item_Stored (was this item stored atleast 1 time).  If it was stored atleast 1 time value should be yes and if the item was never stored atleast 1 time the value should be no.

Shipment_Info_table:

Shipment_Info has three columns ShipmentID and ItemID and Item_Status. ItemID values are always unique, but ShipmentIDs will repeat because different Items can be in the same shipment, and item status can be in different states (Allocated, Filled and Packed).

Item_Info table:
Item_Info has two columns.  ItemID, Operation, Op_time.  ItemIDs will repeat because this table shows the different operations that have occurred to this itemID and the associated times.

DB Table: Shipment_INFO

| ShipmentID | ItemID | Item_status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 20001 | Packed |
| 10002 | 20002 | Allocated |
| 10002 | 20003 | Packed |
| 10003 | 20004 | Filled |
| 10004 | 20005 | Packed |
| 10004 | 20006 | Packed |
| 10004 | 20007 | Packed |
| 10005 | 20008 | Filled |
| 10005 | 20009 | Packed |
| 10006 | 20010 | Filled |

DB Table: Item_Info

| ItemID | Item_status |
| --- | --- |
| 20001 | Induct |
| 20001 | Stock |
| 20002 | Induct |
| 20002 | Stock |
| 20002 | Stored |
| 20002 | Dock |
| 20003 | Induct |
| 20003 | Stock |
| 20003 | Stored |
| 20004 | Induct |
| 20004 | Cancelled |
| 20004 | Stored |
| 20005 | Induct |
| 20005 | Stock |
| 20005 | Stored |
| 20006 | Induct |
| 20006 | Reject |
| 20006 | Induct |
| 20006 | Stock |
| 20007 | Induct |
| 20007 | Stock |
| 20007 | Stored |
| 20007 | Stored |
| 20008 | Induct |
| 20008 | Stock |
| 20008 | Reject |
| 20009 | Induct |
| 20009 | Stock |
| 20009 | Induct |
| 20009 | Stored |
| 20010 | Induct |
| 20010 | Stock |

Ideal Output:

| ShipmentID | ItemID | Shipment_Size | Shipment_Ready | Item_Stored |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 20001 | 1 | Yes | No |
| 10002 | 20002 | 2 | No | Yes |
| 10002 | 20003 | 2 | No | Yes |
| 10003 | 20004 | 1 | No | Yes |
| 10004 | 20005 | 3 | Yes | Yes |
| 10004 | 20006 | 3 | Yes | No |
| 10004 | 20007 | 3 | Yes | Yes |
| 10005 | 20008 | 2 | No | No |
| 10005 | 20009 | 2 | No | Yes |
| 10006 | 20010 | 1 | No | Yes |

The code below gets me the first two columns, but I'm having trouble on how to join 2nd table and get the 3 column. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 select ShipmentID,ItemID,
           count(ItemID) over (partition by ShipmentID) Shipment_Size,
          case when 
      sum(case when Item_status='Packed' then 1 else 0 end) OVER (partition by ShipmentID ) =count(ItemID) over (partition by ShipmentID)
                   then 'Yes' else 'no' end as Shipment_Ready
      from Shipment_INFO
    group by ShipmentID,Item_status,ItemID
```

Comment: Will look into DDL+DML for the future.  I updated the title, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want a simple `case` expression using `exists`:

```
select ShipmentID, ItemID
    , count(ItemID) over (partition by ShipmentID) Shipment_Size
    , case when
        sum(case when Item_status='Packed' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by ShipmentID ) = count(ItemID) over (partition by ShipmentID)
        then 'Yes' else 'No' end as Shipment_Ready
    , case when exists (select 1 from Item_Info ii where ii.ItemId = si.ItemId and ii.Item_Status = 'Stored') then 'Yes' else 'No' end as Item_Stored
from Shipment_INFO si
group by ShipmentID, Item_status, ItemID;
```

Comment: For my own curiousity, would it be more efficient to join the yes/no value into the table as opposed to the subselect? My thoughts initially went to an agg based solution as he had but between the outer case that would be required and the inner case to determine if the row should be counted, that would certainly be a bit more of a hog.

Comment: @ClearlyClueless the only way to know for sure is inspect the execution plan, but in general if you only need a single column from another table then a sub-query will perform exactly the same as a join, cos its doing exactly the same thing. However exists has the potential to perform much better if the appropriate indexes exist, cos it just need to determine whether there is a record or no, hopefully directly from the index.

Comment: The thing to keep in mind is that SQL, unless you add specific query hints, in is only describing the results you want, it in no way determines how the engine retrieves those results. And best practice is to build the query that makes the most logical sense i.e. is easy to understand, and only performance optimise if a performance issue arises.

Comment: @DaleK This worked perfectly thank you so much.  I was wondering if you could help me a little more with what ClearClueless is referring to.  In my example, if Item_Info had a 3rd column called date_time_stamp.  And in my output I would like to show the same view with a 6th column called Stored_Date_time.  And in Column stored_data_time I would like to show the latest time that the itemID was stored.  Would that require to use an agg based solution?

Comment: @DaleK https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75404100/how-to-show-two-calculated-columns-to-an-existing-table